# Debugging webpack.mix.js in VS Code – unverified breakpoint

Tags: node.js, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code, laravel-mix

I'm using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com/) to configure webpack. I have set up a `mix.then()` function inside my `webpack.mix.js`, which I'd like to debug using VS Code.

The code inside `webpack.mix.js` gets executed, but any breakpoints I set will be marked as 'unverified breakpoint' ('breakpoint set but not yet bound'). Debugging any of the webpack files, or even the `webpack.config.js`, works fine.

This is my launch config:

`{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug webpack",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
      "args": [
        "--progress",
        "--hide-modules",
        "--config" , "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
      ],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
      },
    },`

I'm clueless why the code in `webpack.mix.js` gets executed but I cannot set any breakpoints. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually unrelated to Laravel mix. I had **multiple root folders** in my VS Code workspace, which somehow prevented correct debugging. Trimming it down to only one root folder solved the issue.